# How to schedule a task based specific time in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-scheduled

Using `@Scheduled('cron expression')`, we can schedule a task.
But I must run a task based on the timestamp got from the UI dynamically.

How can I do it ?

Comment: Inject the TaskScheduler. use it to schedule your task. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler.html

Comment: http://mbcoder.com/dynamic-task-scheduling-with-spring/